# php tags in success messages

Tags: php, mysql, localhost

I've designed a website with a forum with users, different categories and posts!For that, I already established a mysql database via localhost showing users, categories and posts tables!
The categorie_id of the posts table is interwoven with the categorie title in the categories table as foreign key!

How could I now show the category title from categories table in success message of added posts on my website manage posts table (see picture below)?

I want it to show sthg like this in the success message: "New Music (=category title) post was successfully added!"

I tried it like this, but it didn't show the category title in the success message (please, take a closer look into the row with $_SESSION:['add-post-success'] = ....):

[Manage Posts Table Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZELCS.png)

[categories database table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CNDr8.png)
[posts db table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GadzE.png)

```
 // insert post into database
        $query = "INSERT INTO posts (title, body, thumbnail, category_id, author_id, is_featured) VALUES ('$title', '$body', '$thumbnail_name', $category_id, $author_id, $is_featured)";
        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

        if(!mysqli_errno($connection)) {
            $_SESSION['add-post-success'] = "New <php= {$category['title']} ?> post added successfully";
            header('location: ' . ROOT_URL . 'admin/');
            die();
        }
```

Comment: You don't need php tags in success messages

Comment: But, how could I then automatically insert the respective category title into the success message ?

So far, it has not been working with approaches like this " . $category['title'] . " as we have the foreign key connecting the category title from the other table with the category_id of the posts table (see attached pictures)!

Comment: Just like what you did at the second line.

Comment: You need to add a `SELECT title FROM categories WHERE id = :category_id` query, and execute that with the `$category_id` you just inserted to get the category title. Then concatenate the title you get back from the database into the error message, either with `"New {$category['title']} post added successfully"` or `"New " . $category['title'] . " post added successfully"`.

Comment: It tried it like this:


        $query1 = "SELECT title FROM categories WHERE id = $category_id";
        $result1 = mysqli_query($connection, $query1);

        $category_title = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1);

Comment: You just have EVERYTHING messed up. What **PHP tags** has to do with **foreign keys**? If you cannot get $category['title'] it's one thing. If you need to get $category['title'] into the message it's another. Your question is about the latter. And for this, you DON'T need any tags

Comment: Try either `$category_title = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)['title'];` or `$category_title = mysqli_fetch_column($result1);` for the last line.

Comment: A big thank you to Marleen for your advice - the last line you mentioned in your last post did the thing it was supposed to - I just forget to attach the title in my statement ;)! 

Thank you !